# perform command depending on last known value?

Tags: c, state

```
switch (leds & 0x07) {
    case 1:
        setG510LEDColor(0, 220, 0);
        break;
    case 2:
        setG510LEDColor(220, 0, 0);
        break;
    case 4:
        setG510LEDColor(0, 0, 220);
        break;
    default:
        setG510LEDColor(000, 220, 000);
}
```

The above is my code (Should i have a break; in default?)
I was wondering if i can set the default to do a command based on what the last known state was of (leds & 0x07) was. for example if it was 2 i want to do 1 command, if it was 1 i want to do another and if it was 4 i want to do another, then if it was none of these i want to do something else.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

1) yes you should add a break even after default. This is done so that after many days, when somebody will add something at the end of case statement, he/she need not to worry if the default is break terminated or not.

2) I am confused. Do you want to use the last switch value? then why not store it in some global state holder and use it in default? you can do it at the end of switch statement, also take care for the first time it comes to switch. or is it something else?